# Bootstrap ie menu issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-7, responsive-design

I'm new to Bootstrap. I created a web site it's working fine in all other browser in IE 7 it showing the site as mobile version. In ie 7 menu converted to drop down. The screen shots are below:

[image: Firefox screenshot]
[image: IE 7 screenshot]

Comment: Ummm... U forgot the screenshots at home...

Comment: i suggest you to don't even worry about IE7. people has to upgrade anyway.

Comment: not allow to add screen shots

Comment: @NREZ screenshots added sorry

Comment: Alright... This is strange... Do you have a mobile website as well... Then check [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/internet-explorer-8-redirects-to-mobile-layout/5b0fe536-aa0e-4ba5-999a-60f299928f5a) out...

Comment: there is no solutions available so i switched to Bootstrap 2.3.2 working fine :)

Comment: That is good... Am happy things are back on track for you...